# Mapping User table from Asp.Net Identity in AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, automapper

In Asp.Net Core I overrode the IdentityUser table to add more functionalities

```
public class Person : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Location {get; set; }
        public SellerType SellerType{get; set; }

    }
    public enum SellerType 
    {
        PrivateSeller , 
        Dealer
    }
```

I also have a ViewModel class CredentialModel which I am chaining with the Person class with AutoMapper

```
public class CredentialModel
  {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get; set; }
    public string Location {get; set; }
    public string SellerType{get; set; }
    public string[] SellerTypes {get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set; }
  }
```

And the AutoMapper Profile Class

```
public class UserMapProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserMapProfile(){
          CreateMap<CarAdderUser, CredentialModel>()
             .ForMember(model=> model.SellerType , 
             opt=> opt.MapFrom(vm=>((SellerType)vm.SellerType).ToString()))
             .ForMember(model=> model.SellerTypes, opt=> opt.UseValue(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SellerType)).ToArray()))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

My problem is in the Controller

Like this it works but i am returning the entity not the VM

```
    [HttpGet("getUser/{username}")]
     public  IActionResult GetUser(string username)
     {
         var user= _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
         return Ok(user);
     }
```

Like this it throws me a 404 in Postman

```
[HttpGet("getUser/{username}")]
     public  IActionResult GetUser(string username)
     {
         var user= _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
         return Ok(_mapper.Map<CredentialModel>(user));
     }
```

IT throws me an error

```
 An unhandled exception has occurred: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

      Mapping types:
      Task`1 -> CredentialModel
```

Not sure what to do ... Not an AutoMapper expert

Answer (score 0):

Solved ... the problem was that I forgot that I only need the result ...
so user.Result instead of user in the return ...
Not sure what the other things are ... They are not columns in the User table in the DB

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `user.Result`. That will block the calling thread. Use `async/await` instead.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(string username)
 {
     var user= await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
     return Ok(_mapper.Map<CredentialModel>(user));
 }
```